# Definite and indefinite Articles when to write the right one

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

I know the rule of definite and indefinite articles ( A, An ), but I see lots of people who speak English as their native mother language and they write a sentences like this :
"I like a apple." should not that be "I like an apple ?." this really confuses me

Comment: There are various dialects and sociolects. In some of them, this distinction between "an" and "a" is not made.

Comment: I can imagine some native speakers *speaking* this way, but it's hard for me to imagine "a lot" of native speakers *writing* it.  But as people point out, there are many dialects, sociolects, regiolects, etc.  And plenty of people who just get things wrong!

Answer (score -1):

It is entirely possible that some native speakers would write (write?)

> I like a apple.

though I've never seen it written this way, and you are correct in thinking the article should be

> I like *an* apple.

but actually, the correct sentence would be

> I *would* like *an* apple.

When spoken, what might be said is

> I wanna apple.

depending on dialect, but what is not said is

> I wanna**n** apple.

Comment: It is entirely possible that some native speakers would write (write?)

I like a apple.  How is that possible this is grammatically wrong the first letter in apple is "a" which is a vowel.

Comment: “How is that possible?” – people make all kinds of mistakes; “the first letter in ‘apple’ is ‘a’ which is a vowel” – yeah, so? It's the sound the word begins with that matters in this case.

Comment: @DavidPowell  You can't count on publication to guarantee that any given text conforms to 'Standard' English. A great deal of the English you encounter, especially on the internet, is casual and hasty, riddled with typographical errors which the authors are not concerned to correct; and some of it is written employing the non-'Standard' forms of a particular speech community. Things may be different in your own language (but I'd be surprised if this were the case).

Comment: @DavidPowell Can you propose a solution to the problem of mistakes in article use, or other grammatical errors? Should a newspaper or website host be fined or otherwise punished for each transgression?

Comment: I would say "I wannan apple" (although I'd write "I want an apple"). I don't get why you say this doesn't exist.

Comment: "Wanna" is idiomatic, similar to "gotta" and "hava".  If you intend to say "I wanna apple" for effect (e.g. accent), but say "I wannnan apple", my guess would be most people might think you meant to say "I want an apple" and thereby you would lose the effect.